# Purchased SSL Cert but can't attach to a website

Tags: ssl, iis

I purchased a wildcard SSL cert from GoDaddy. I completed the email verification phase, then they provided me with a "generated-csr.txt" file and a "generated-private-key.txt" file. They then provided me with a zip file containing a .crt .pem and .p7b file. I followed their instructions - installed the .p7b file in the intermediate certification authority repository. I then did a complete certificate request as instructed and went to my websites binding and attempted to select the certificate which wasn't there.

I can see the cert in the web-hosting repository but without as has been mentioned a private key. I have a private key in the .txt file, but I don't know what to do with it.

Can someone please shed some light on where this process might have gone wrong?

Comment: How was the CSR (+private key) generated in the first place? How did the private key end up in a text file? I find it rather concerning that it sounds like someone else provided the key to you (I would consider the key compromised if this is the case).

You *can* import for instance a p12/pfx archive with both the cert and key, but if you are using Windows/IIS, normally you would have the key already in the Windows certificate repository when you generated the CSR and then only import the signed certificate that you get back from the CA to have the whole set in the repository.

Answer (score 3):

```
they provided me with a "generated-csr.txt" file and a "generated-private-key.txt" file
```

That seems quite wrong.

The standard process for requesting a certificate should be as follows:

- *YOU* generate a Certificate Signing Request.
- When creating the CSR, a private key is also generated and *stored on your computer*.
- You send the CSR to the Certification Authority.
- The CA approves the CSR and signs it.
- You import the answer from the CA in the same computer where you generated the CSR, on which the private key is stored.
- At this point, you have a complete and fully working certificate.
- **The private key of the certificate never left your computer; not even the CA should have it.**

If the CA sent you both the CSR and the private key, this is the very opposite of what should have happened.

[There are several ways to combine the pieces you have into a working certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key); but the whole process appears to be completely botched and I wouldn't trust that certificate for anything.

Comment: well to be honest i don't really understand any of it. I've worked in IT for over 30 years and this is far and away the most convoluted and difficult process I've ever come across. I literally go to the godaddy website purchase a wildcard ssl cert *.domain.com pay the money, verify we own the domain via email link and they supply those files then a zip file with the certificate files I mentioned. If I revoke the cert I presume I can do it properly via csr.

Comment: Several "cheap" Certification Authorities do what you say, supposedly to make your life easier; they generate the CSR and the private key for you and then send you everything; but this completely breaks the intended purpose of a certificate, which is that *only you* should own the private key.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to combine the files you have into a single PFX file you can import in IIS, have a look at the question I linked.

Comment: right well I seem to have stumbled on a solution of sorts... I requested to rekey my cert to which I attached the CSR i generated from my website... I was then able to import the cert (crt) and export it as a .cer and complete the CSR request and change the binding on my sites https to the new certificate. Thanks for the linked question I will take a look at that. I don't remember godaddy asking me to upload a CSR or anything when purchasing the cert.... thanks to those that tried to help me it is much appreciated.

Comment: CSR are mostly useless nowadays anyway because CA asks for the information separately, see https://www.agwa.name/blog/post/security_review_of_cfssl_signer_code#2098-appendix for details. What some CA do, if you trust them of course, is that during sign up, they will generate the private key inside the browser using only the internal functions, so the key never leaves the browser and you have a way to get it that way and store it where appropriate, and then after validation, you get the certificate later.

Answer (score 0):

right well I seem to have stumbled on a solution of sorts... I requested to rekey my cert to which I attached the CSR i generated from my website... I was then able to import the cert (crt) and export it as a .cer and complete the CSR request and change the binding on my sites https to the new certificate. Thanks for the linked question I will take a look at that. I don't remember godaddy asking me to upload a CSR or anything when purchasing the cert....

Comment: If you do appreciate "the linked question", you should accept that answer, not posting your own.

Comment: What? Why should I accept an answer that wasn't an answer? I answered my own question because I figured out what I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use Notepad++ to encode the goDaddy .txt file in UTF-8 only. rename file to .PEM - Done! You have your key.

Skips the whole conversion rigamarole.

GoDaddy gives you only one chance to save this file in the request process, they do not keep it. If you didn't save it, you have to rekey the cert. I do not know why they don't post this in their docs.